# How to code a PowerPoint VBA Macro that "stacks" shapes on top of/touching each other?

Tags: vba, powerpoint, shapes

I'm trying to find a way to make a macro that "stacks" shapes right next to each other, sort of like how a totem pole is stacked, with the shapes basically touching each other. The idea here is that it would be really helpful for items like chevron timelines, or making sure that shapes are as close as they can be without overlapping.

So far, my code thought process has been something like this, assuming that I want to stack from the bottom up:

Select all shapes

For shapes in the selection:

Collect the bottom position and top position of each shape

Using the lowest shape as a reference, place the second lowest shape at position (lowest shape 
  coordinates minus shape height)

Using the second lowest shape as a reference, place the third lowest shape at position (second lowest 
  shape minus second lowest shape height)

And so on until all the shapes are stacked on top of each other. I imagine the code could be easily modified for stacking top to bottom, or stacking left to right.

Biggest question is, how do I make this code? I've gone through the tutorials on how to move objects, but I can't seem to get it to do it with more than two objects.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
Sub Stack_on_top()
Dim Shp1 As Shape
Dim Shp2 As Shape
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer

  x = Windows(1).Selection.ShapeRange.Count
  For y = 1 To x
    If Shp1 Is Nothing Then
      Set Shp1 = Windows(1).Selection.ShapeRange(y)
    Else
      Set Shp2 = Windows(1).Selection.ShapeRange(y)
          Shp2.Top = Shp1.Top - Shp2.Height
      End If
  Next y
End Sub
```

Problem is, this code only does it with 2 objects, the rest just stack based off of the one reference.
Any help would be highly appreciated!

Thanks!

-John

Answer (score 1):

Try like so:

```
Sub Stack_on_top()

Dim Shp1 As Shape
Dim Shp As Shape
Dim x As Long
Dim sngLastY As Single

    Set Shp1 = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
    sngLastY = Shp1.Top

    For x = 2 To ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Count
        Set Shp = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(x)
        With Shp
            .Left = Shp1.Left
            .Top = sngLastY - .Height
            sngLastY = .Top
        End With
    Next

End Sub
```

[Later ... adding shapes to array]

```
Function SelectedShapesToArray(ShRange As ShapeRange) As Variant

    Dim aTemparray() As Shape
    ReDim aTemparray(1 To ShRange.Count)
    Dim x As Long

    For x = 1 To ShRange.Count
        Set aTemparray(x) = ShRange(x)
    Next

    SelectedShapesToArray = aTemparray

End Function

Sub Test()

    Dim x As Long
    Dim ShArray() As Shape

    ShArray = SelectedShapesToArray(ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange)

    ' Test: do we have all the shapes we expected?
    For x = LBound(ShArray) To UBound(ShArray)
        Debug.Print ShArray(x).Name
    Next

    ' Here you could sort ShArray on ShArray(x).top

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, this is fantastic! One quick follow up: Is there an way too make it automatically know which shape is the lowest, and then use that as the starting point (sort of like in "Align Bottom")?

Comment: You could add the selected shapes to an array, sort the array, then step through the array rather than through the shaperange.

Comment: I'll poke around here to figure out how to do that. Thank you for the steer! If you have any helpful link that explains how to do that, I'd love to see it. Thanks again! this is super helpful.

Comment: See edited version of my original post. Next, it's easy to find lots of array sorting routines on the web. For the small number of shapes you'll likely be dealing with, speed/efficiency is not likely to be a concern. Pick whichever method is easiest to understand.